# Facebook Business SDK and error AH02429: Response header name contains invalid characters

Tags: php, facebook, composer-php

I am trying to install Facebook SDK for Business:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/business-sdk/getting-started

I am using the "composer" way.
My environment is a cPanel hosting with PHP 7.3.
Server version: Apache/2.4.51 (cPanel)

When I open https:// mysite .org/fbsdk/test.php I get this error in Apache:

```
[Tue Jan 04 12:58:53.579914 2022] [http:error] [pid 1726:tid 47121819059968] [client 192.168.10.10:58450] AH02429: Response header name 'FacebookAds\\CrashReporter ' contains invalid characters, aborting request
```

This is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "name/fbsdk",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "facebook/php-business-sdk": "^8.0.3"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "armitage",
            "email": "mymail@mydomain.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

any suggestion?
Thank you!

Comment: Please share more details. How is the given problem related to Composer?

Comment: Hi Nico. I chose composer to install Facebook SDK (between different options: nodejs, python, and so on). I used this command to install: `/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/bin/php -d allow_url_fopen=1 $(which composer) install`. When I access test.php through browser, I get the error I wrote in my first post. Thankyou!

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. This should also include the code you are using and the attempts to resolve the problem. Also, I doubt that Composer itself is related to the problem